# displaying google maps with html5 geolocation in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, google-maps, geolocation

im trying to display google maps using html5 geolocation, the code is working fine is jsfiddle but in my mvc application, the map is not being displayed..posting the code below..
this is the link
http://jsfiddle.net/PhzsR/62/

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>


<div id="results"></div>

<div id="map"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var $message_area = jQuery('#results');
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$message_area.html('<i>Locating you...</i>  ');
if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(


    function foundLocation(position) {
        $message_area.children().remove();

        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

        var map;


        var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var options = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: centerPosition,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: centerPosition,
            map: map,
            icon: 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/sailboat-tourism.png'
        });

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: centerPosition,
            radius: accuracy,
            map: map,
            fillColor: '#0000FF',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0
        });




        map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());






        $message_area.append('Your latitude: ' + latitude + ' and longitude: ' + longitude + ' and accuracy: ' + accuracy + ':')
    }, function (error) {
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                $message_area.append('Timeout error while finding your location');
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                $message_area.append('Position unavailable error while finding your location');
                break;
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                $message_area.append('Permission denied error while finding your location');
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                $message_area.append('Unknown error while finding your location');
                break;
        }
    });






}
});

</script>
```

do i need to add any reference for displaying google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the 'manage resources' tab on your fiddle, you've got a reference to Google Maps API which isn't in your code above, make sure you add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: done with that, even now the map is not being displayed, but positive is that after adding the script, the latitude and longitude values are displayed...pls check my edited code in my question

Comment: By default the map div won't have a height, so it will collapse up but will probably all be working. Try adding an explicit height to the `#map` div, e.g. `<div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>`